# C# foreach json get value by the same key

Tags: c#, foreach, json.net

I have a json

```
[{"id": "856493604074422302", "type": 1, "last_message_id": "984001117388148799", "recipients": [{"id": "212159523759981524", "username": "username1", "avatar": null, "avatar_decoration": null, "discriminator": "5423", "public_flags": 0}]}, {"id": "986934778819383320", "type": 1, "last_message_id": "986934782049009715", "recipients": [{"id": "899330127958270044", "username": "username2", "avatar": null, "avatar_decoration": null, "discriminator": "0100", "public_flags": 0}]}]
```

And I want to get every ID of the users in a foreach statement.

Should look like that

```
foreach (var id in ids)
{
   Console.WriteLine("ID: " + id);
}
```

Also, is there a way to bypass the first ID (which is my user), and get straight to the other IDs where is the recipients? So that I would get `212159523759981524` and `899330127958270044` only.

I have tried

```
HttpResponse json = request.Get("the url where i get the json");
var json2 = json.ToString();
var array = JArray.Parse(json2);
var id = array[0]["id"].ToString();

foreach (var ids in id)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID: " + ids);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = JArray.Parse(json2);
foreach (dynamic entry in array.Skip(1))    // skip first user
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID: " + entry.recipients[0].id);
}
```

Comment: forgot the array index sorry

Comment: What http requests? I don't see anything in the question about it.